# CSS 2x3 grid layot issue

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues with a 2x3 grid layout I am trying to accomplish. http://johns-webdesign.com/portfolioV2/ The grid needs to look like this:

```
X | X | X
X | X | X
```

As you can see, one of the divs just seem to float under the grid layout. Without going to css tables I just can't figure out how to fix this.

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="metro_left">
        <h1 style="color: #f7a70e">Here is some of my latest work</h1>
        <div id="latest_work_gallery"><img src="images/current_work.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
            <div class="image_caption"><a href="#">mX Fabrications</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="latest_work_gallery"><img src="images/current_work.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
            <div class="image_caption"><a href="#">mX Fabrications</a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="content_spacer_down"></div>

        <div id="latest_work_gallery"><img src="images/current_work.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
            <div class="image_caption"><a href="#">mX Fabrications</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="latest_work_gallery"><img src="images/current_work.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
            <div class="image_caption"><a href="#">mX Fabrications</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="latest_work_gallery"><img src="images/current_work.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
            <div class="image_caption"><a href="#">mX Fabrications</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="latest_work_gallery"><img src="images/current_work.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
            <div class="image_caption"><a href="#">mX Fabrications</a></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    width:1200px;
    height:580px;
}
#metro_left {
    padding:0;margin:0;float:left;
    width:800px;
    height:560px;
}
#latest_work_gallery {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    margin:5px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    background-color: #f7a70e;
}
#latest_work_gallery:hover {
    margin:10px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1); 
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1); 
    -o-transform: scale(1.1); 
    transform: scale(1.1); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod='scale')alpha(opacity = 100); /*For IE 8 and less */
}
.image_caption {
    clear:both;
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    width:220px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    background-color:#56FB39;
    opacity:0.8;
}
.image_caption a{color:#000;}
```

I tried switching the floats, just mirrors the issue. Also tried to clear left, right or both. No anvil

Comment: Uhhh. You have spacer down after the second div....

Comment: For this you can use a de-styled unordered list. Make the UL three times wider than LI and float:left on the LI. It makes this a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete:

```
<div class="content_spacer_down"></div>
```

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem. delete it then hover over the images.

Comment: @EricLemos - Probably due to the CSS hover on `#latest_work_gallery:hover`

Answer (score 0):

You have two divs, then `.content_spaver_down` then 4 divs. rearrange the order.

```
   <div id="content">
        <div id="metro_left">
            <h1 style="color: #f7a70e">Here is some of my latest work</h1>
            <div id="latest_work_gallery"><img src="images/current_work.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
                <div class="image_caption"><a href="#">mX Fabrications</a></div>
            </div>

            <div id="latest_work_gallery"><img src="images/current_work.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
                <div class="image_caption"><a href="#">mX Fabrications</a></div>
            </div>

            <div id="latest_work_gallery"><img src="images/current_work.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
                <div class="image_caption"><a href="#">mX Fabrications</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="content_spacer_down"></div>

            <div id="latest_work_gallery"><img src="images/current_work.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
                <div class="image_caption"><a href="#">mX Fabrications</a></div>
            </div>

            <div id="latest_work_gallery"><img src="images/current_work.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
                <div class="image_caption"><a href="#">mX Fabrications</a></div>
            </div>

            <div id="latest_work_gallery"><img src="images/current_work.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
                <div class="image_caption"><a href="#">mX Fabrications</a></div>
            </div>



        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've places the  after the first two block. Since they float right, one block is missing. Delete the above div or move it, so it will appear after the first three divs.